# How to share files between Ubuntu and Mac OS X

Tags: linux, macos, ubuntu

Is there any links/tutorials/videos that helps me share files between Ubuntu and Mac OS X?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you want to share on a local network

> On OS
>   X. Click on System Preferences -->
>   Sharing. 
>   Make sure the Services tab is
>   selected. Choose one of the sharing
>   methods, either UNIX sharing or
>   Windows sharing.
>
> On your Ubuntu machine, go to Places
>   --> Connect to server and enter the sharing details.

Have a look at this forum http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=353584

Comment: This didn't work for me because it's now (2023) outdated, but I found a complete and useful guide to setting up sharing on Mac OS Ventura [here](https://www.stratospherix.com/support/how-to-enable-file-sharing-on-mac.php).  The first 3/4 of the article is about setting up the Mac and when you get down to "Scan your network" section, the rest is about Linux.  You may have to make minor modifications in the Linux section, depending on which distribution you're using (for example in Ubuntu, the "Other Locations" option is in the sidebar of the Files app).

Answer (score 3):

It's not the smartest way to share files, but on Ubuntu you can simply use Share Folder option in the context menu, set settings as you wish and thats all. (Relogin may be required.)
Then on MAC Ubuntu share should be discoverable.

Comment: I wonder why this wouldn't be a smart way to do it? Sounds good to me!

Comment: Probably because many perople think using SMB protocol in Linux is not "right".

Comment: What context menu are you referring to?

Answer (score 2):

I'm also using Ubuntu 10.04 and I can connect to my machines using their name. Say I have computers named ernie and bert that are on the same network:

```
ernie:~$ ping bert.local
ernie:~$ echo hello > file.txt
ernie:~$ scp file.txt bert.local:~/copied-from-ernie.txt
```

You can use this in nautilus too. Enter `ssh://bert.local` into the nautilus location bar in ubuntu (hit Ctrl-L to select the location bar) and hit enter. If you have different user names use `ssh://username@bert.local`

I think you can do something similar in the Finder location bar.

You have to install/enable sshd for this to work:

- Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install openssh-server` (you may need to restart)
- Mac: System Preferences --> Sharing. Check the "Remote Login" box.

Answer (score -2):

Why not use Dropbox? I found it's a pretty easy and convenient way of sharing files.
Also it is a cross-system solution, so you might use it for taking files to a further windows computer, too. However, I have not yet tried Ubuntu<->Mac but only Windows-Mac, which worked beautifully.

Comment: That's not the answer to his problem. Assume he doesn't have internet connection on those machines. Will dropbox still be able to provide this functionality.